# How to use NGINX reverse proxy, and proxy the port and path to the upstream url?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I've set up nginx reverse proxy as per the instructions here: https://medium.com/@mightywomble/how-to-set-up-nginx-reverse-proxy-with-lets-encrypt-8ef3fd6b79e5

My sites-enabled/mysite.conf looks like

```
server {      
 server_name mynginxreverseproxy.com; 
 set $upstream serverip:$server_port/; 
 location / {  
    proxy_pass_header Authorization;  
    proxy_pass http://$upstream;  
    proxy_set_header Host $host;  
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP 
    $remote_addr; 
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For 
    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;  
    proxy_http_version 1.1;  
    proxy_set_header Connection “”;  
    proxy_buffering off;  
    client_max_body_size 0;  
    proxy_read_timeout 36000s;  
    proxy_redirect off;  }

    listen 443 ssl; # paths to ssl cert files

} server {
    if ($host = mynginxreverseproxy.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


 server_name mynginxreverseproxy.com; listen 80;
    return 404; 

}
```

I would like to forward the port and path to my server, such as  https://mynginxreverseproxy.com:portnumber/myurl -> to serverip:com:portnumber/myurl.  I've been able to get this working for a single port which can forward port 80 to my desired port, but how to I scale it out to work for many ports?

**I have many port mapping that I'd like to set up, so it would be ideal to do this using a variable, rather than hardcoding each port mapping.**

How do I pass the port and path through using a variable in the conf file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually got this working after a lot of debugging and configurations.

The

`set $upstream serverip:$server_port`

was correct, but I was missing the

`listen` directive which allows the NGINX server to listen on a particular port, it listens on port 80 by default.  However, port 80 was not the port which I wanted to get passed through to the upstream server.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps someone would find it useful, there is an online utility where you can generate an nginx configuration. Very user friendly

You can find it [here](https://nginxconfig.io/)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this (sample config below)

```
upstream myserver {
    server ip-address:port;
}

server {
  listen 80;      //IPv4
  listen [::]:80; //IPv6
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://myserver /;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    ...rest of your headers...
  }
}
```